# No icons on greeter

Tags: 14.04, icons, unity-greeter

When I fired up my 14.04 virtual machine today I was surprised to see this.

[image]

All the functionality is there, if I put the cursor in the upper right corner I get the dropdown menu to Suspend or Shutdown.  But my wallpaper is gone and all the icons.

Looking in the apt logs, the last thing I installed was `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev` because of an error message I received when doing updates.  I then ran the suggested command

`gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache`

Everything seemed OK when I shut down.

I removed this package and all its orphaned dependencies but it did not help.

When I log on, all my icons are gone on the panel as well.  But I think this is bigger than a user-level issue, because it affects the greeter.

This is a VM, so I can reinstall without too much trouble.  But it's basically a clone of my main system, so I'd like to know what caused it, in case it happens to my real system.

What could cause these symptoms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like either the "fix" suggested by the update, or the reason that this fix was suggested, caused the problem.  Reinstalled the package and ran

```
sudo gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache
sudo gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache
```

Rebooted and got all icons back.

[Source](https://therebellin.com/questions/question/missing-icons-after-last-update)